# Live edit current script on Windows

Tags: perl

I would like to live edit the source code of the current script on Windows.

The following script edits itself on OSX to pad each line up till the __DATA__ section to 64 chars in length.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use open IO => ':raw';

# Convert every line of source file to 64 characters long
{
    local @ARGV = $0;
    local $^I   = '.bak';
    while (<>) {
        if ( 1 .. /^__DATA__/ ) {
            s{(\h*#*)(?=\R|\z)}{
                (' ' x (63 - length($_) + length($1))) . '#'
            }e;
        }
        print;
    }
    unlink "$0$^I";    # Delete backup
}

__DATA__
Hello World
```

Source code after running once on darwin:

```
use strict;                                                   #
use warnings;                                                 #
                                                              #
use open IO => ':raw';                                        #
                                                              #
# Convert every line of source file to 64 characters long     #
{                                                             #
    local @ARGV = $0;                                         #
    local $^I   = '.bak';                                     #
    while (<>) {                                              #
        if ( 1 .. /^__DATA__/ ) {                             #
            s{(\h*#*)(?=\R|\z)}{                              #
                (' ' x (63 - length($_) + length($1))) . '#'  #
            }e;                                               #
        }                                                     #
        print;                                                #
    }                                                         #
    unlink "$0$^I";    # Delete backup                        #
}                                                             #
                                                              #
__DATA__                                                      #
Hello World
```

However, when run in Strawberry Perl 5.18.2, I get the following error:

```
Can't do inplace edit on selfedit.pl: File exists at selfedit.pl line 10.
```

This is just a proof of concept, but is there a way to live edit the source code of the current script on Windows?  Using [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPLACE_EDIT) ?

Comment: Sounds like a windows file permissions issue...  The script is a "file in use" and therefore cannot be edited by something else... unless Strawberry Perl has a flag for "run script in read/write mode"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, one can't delete or rename a file that's open unless it was opened with a flag that allows this (`FILE_SHARE_DELETE`). Perl does not use that flag when it opens a file. When you reach `<>`, it tries to rename `$0` to `$0.bak`, but it fails because Perl still has the file open as `DATA`. Adding `close(DATA);` gets beyond that error (and leaves you with a mishandling of line endings).

Comment: Adding `close DATA;` fixed the issue.  There's no mishandling of the line endings though, because I want `length` to report the `:raw` and not the `:crlf` value.

Comment: You produce garbage since you place the spaces and `#` between the CR and the LF

Comment: In earlier incarnation of the script I used `(?=\R|$)` in anticipation that issue, but simplified the regex while debugging a different bug.  I'll test a little and edit my question if I reproduce what you're talking about, which I suspect I will now.

Comment: `type file.pl` is how I noticed the problem.

Comment: Finally was able to take the windows laptop out of the closet and confirmed.  Fixed question to use my original regex.